Understanding the Schrodinger flow——Symplectic Banach manifold
When I reading the paper "Schrodinger flow of maps into symplectic manifolds,1998", I'm confused by the concept symplectic Banach manifold.
For the readers' convenient, I carry the material in the paper to here:
Let $(N,\omega)$ be a symplectic manifold, and let $J$ be an almost complex structure on N such that $$h(\cdot,\cdot):=\omega(\cdot,J\cdot)$$ be the Riemannian metric. It is well known that any smooth function $f$ on $N$ corresponds to a Hamiltonian vector field $V_f$, which is given by the relation$$df(v)=\omega(v,V_f).$$ From $h(\cdot,\cdot):=\omega(\cdot,J\cdot)$  one easily derives $$V_f=J{\rm grad} f,$$ where ${\rm grad} f$ denotes the gradient of $f$ with respect to the metric $h$. The flow is defined by ode$$\dot{u}=J(u){\rm grad}f(u)$$ is called the Hamilton flow of Hamiltonian function $f$.
It is natural to generalize the notion of Hamiltonian flow to an infinite-dimensional setting.
Let $(M, g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and let $X=C^k(M,N)(k\geq1)$. We may consider $X$ as a symplectic Banach manifold with the symplectic form $\Omega$ defined by $$\Omega(u)(v,w)=\int_{M}\omega(u)(v,w)dv_{g},\forall u\in X,\forall v,w\in T_{u}X$$
Similarly, we define an inner product on the tangent bundle $TX$ by
$$\langle v,w\rangle_{u}=\int_{M}h(u)(v,w)dv_{g},\forall u\in X,\forall v,w\in T_{u}X$$
For $F\in C^1(X,\mathbb{R})$ is any functional, we let $T_{F}$ be the gradient of $F$ with respect to the above inner product, i.e.$$dF(u)(v)=\langle T_{F}(u),v\rangle$$Then one can show that the corresponding Hamiltonian vector field$V_F$ (satisfying$$dF(u)(v) 
= Q(u)(v,V_F(u))$$ has the expression
$$V_F(u) = J(u)T_F(u)$$
Here my question is why $X$ is a symplectic Banach manifold? I'm not familiar with infinite dimensional geometry. Isn't $X$ a flat Banach space? why we call it Banach manifold, in addition, they add the term sympletic Banach manifold , and at the beginning of the paragraph, the symplectic form is defined for finite dimensional symplectic form, but here it seems that $\omega(u)$ is defined on infinite dimensional... The following about metric $h$ is similar, I don not know if it is defined on finite dimensional space nor infinite?
Any hints are wellcome, thanks ahead!

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/472419/understanding-the-schrodinger-flow-symplectic-banach-manifold, this question is settled by mathoverflow
